# How to auto-install a software by powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I can initialize the installation of a software.
However, it needs me to manually click next, next, and finish buttons.
I want to include these activities into PowerShell script.

I can easily use `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]:: SendWait()` to control the keyboard to click these buttons.

But how can I wait for the GUI application to ask me to select which buttons?

For example:
click next -> install something -> click next -> install something -> click finish

How can I wait for the installation done and buttons come up?
So that I can just send a key to click them to continue.

Comment: What sort of installation package is it?  If it's a `.msi` there is probably a more automated route you can take, and other non-msi based ones often allow scripting with command line params.

Comment: There should be a command line installation or silent installation available for the software. If not , then its not possible to automate the installation without any other APIs

Comment: Using `SendKeys` to simulate clicks is totally approximative because if you lose focus on the program window, it will be a mess...

Comment: I'm trying to install HCK Manager

Comment: 1) This is not a stackoverflow question but rather a superuser question. 2) Ask the vendor how to do a silent install.